# HTML5 Canvas 2D lighting and normal maps

Tags: 2d, html5, normal-mapping, lighting

How using the HTML5 Canvas can I create a 2D game with light sources and also add an extra depth using normal maps.  I have never really done lighting in 2D before and I'm not sure where to start.

Something like this:

[image: Example 1]

or

[image: Example 2]
<sub>(source: [wholehog-games.com](http://www.wholehog-games.com/devblog/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/lit.png))</sub>

Comment: Your question is too broad to answer. Please be more specific.

Comment: More specific in what way? Also this is going into my 2D game engine.

Comment: Those screenshots you posted are a good way to show what you were actually talking about.

Comment: Good.  The question is do you know the answer?

Comment: 2D lighting is a broad topic; probably too broad to explain in an answer post.  Also, this site doesn't offer tutorials, or otherwise list how-to-get-started advice.  Your best bet is to ask google to find a complete tutorial series on 2d lighting.  It will take a lot of studying and practice to master, but that will allow you to fit it into your own game and art style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This effect is likely done with blending modes.
http://blogs.adobe.com/webplatform/2014/02/24/using-blend-modes-in-html-canvas/

You would create a gradient light texture like:
[image: Lightmap]
and set the composition/blending mode to either additive or multiply (or some other mode for a different effect) and then draw it on top of the area you want lit up.

I'll see if i can include a demo
Edit: http://jsfiddle.net/6dzsbhpp/1/

As per normal mapping, this must be done by hand, see: http://29a.ch/2010/3/24/normal-mapping-with-javascript-and-canvas-tag

Comment: The OP also asked for normal mapping.  Though if that part of the question is removed, it would become a much more reasonably scoped problem.

Comment: Updated with link to normal mapping